# Get IIS6 to serve JSON files (inc. POST,GET)?

Tags: json, iis, iis-6

By default, IIS6 does not serve .json (no wildcard `MIME` type).

Therefore a 404 not found is thrown. I then add a new MIME type `(.json, text/plain or application/x-javascript or application/json)` which works fine.

However, when you then add a new mapping `(Home Directory -> Configuration -> Add) with .json, C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll`, "`GET,POST`" and try to browse to the file, you get a 404.

If you remove the mapping and try and `POST or GET` to it, you get a `405`.

...

Suggestions?

Comment: On my machine your configuration works without the errors. Have you replicated this behaviour? Can you post the iis log files of the failed requests?

Answer (score 108):

By default, IIS in W2K3 and above won't serve files that aren't of a MIME type that it knows about (instead returning 404 errors).

You need to add a MIME type to IIS to allow it to serve that type of file. You can set it at the site level or at the server level.

To set this for the entire server:

- Open the properties for the server in IIS Manager and click MIME Types
- Click "New". Enter "JSON" for the extension and "application/json" for the MIME type.

---

### Update

Given this post is found in the Sencha "getting started guide", I thought it's worth *upgrading* the steps.

On Win 7 Enterprise SP 1 with 64-bit
The IIS has a different outlook. So the steps:

*. Open IIS Manager. Then you get following window.

[image]

*. Right click on MIME and choose `open feature`

*. Click on ADD from top right corner Actions menu

[image]

*. Rest is as per Evan's.

Comment: FYI this will take the server offline. At least it did for me after I clicked Apply.

Comment: @styfle - That's odd. Modifying the MIME map shouldn't disrupt the server's operation at all. That's definitely not an intended behavior.

Comment: That's what I thought but I kind of knocked a few hundred people offline for a minute this morning...

Comment: @EvanAnderson is it `JSON` or `.json`?, given it's an extention... **I noticed that `json` becomes automatically an extension when added. I am updating your answer with a screen shot for people like me.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have Active Server Pages Allowed in the Web Service Extensions section of your IIS configuration.

IIS Manager -> (local computer) -> Web Service Extensions -> Active Server Pages

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have IIS installed, obviously, you'll want to install it prior to launching the IIS Manager. I needed (on Windows 7) to go to: 'control panel/program and features' then click 'turn windows features on or off'

Reference: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/how-to-install-iis-on-windows-vista/

It appears that starting the IIS Manager is different for different systems. I did 'start/run/inetmgr.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763170(v=vs.100).aspx

Reference: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770472(v=ws.10).aspx

Troy Frericks.
#

Comment: This doesnt answer the OP question