# get IIS6+ to load JSON files without server-wide change?

Tags: json, iis-7, iis-6

I've got a PHP-based web app that runs on all kinds of my customer's servers, mostly apache, but sometimes IIS. I'm using a bunch of **JSON** files for storing image URL data to be loaded by flash elements.

**Problem: IIS6+ won't load a .json file, it returns a 404 error** because it's not a *known* mime type (why IIS doesn't recognize .json is beyond me).

I've googled this a bunch, and read this SO post:

[Get IIS6 to serve JSON files (inc. POST,GET)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332988/get-iis6-to-serve-json-files-inc-post-get)

But I'm trying to figure out a way to convince IIS to accept the JSON files **without the user having to contact their webhost and ask them to make a server-wide change.  Is this possible?** Is there something sort of like a `php_ini` setting or some sort of script-based solution to tell IIS that .json's are OK?

If the answer to above is NO, I've read a few places suggesting setting the json file extension to `.txt`, which I've confirmed works on the IIS7 server I'm troubleshooting on, with no apparent deleterious effects to the flash elements. If I had to, could I write all of the json files as .txt instead?  Would there be any down-sides to doing it that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IIS6, unfortunately, unless you can persuade all your customers to add the `.json` mime type, you're kind of out of luck.

I don't see any downside of storing the JSON content as say `.json.txt` however.

On IIS 7, if the hoster has delegated control of the `<staticContent>` configuration section in `<system.webServer>` to the site user then you can control this in the `web.config` file.

Comment: ok, thanks. looks like i'm going to go with the route of serving them all with the extension .txt