# How do I consume JSON from a web service in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, json

We have a web application providing a service using a simple REST interface (GET/POST methods) and returning results in JSON format.

A client wants to use the service from an ASP application (I assume ASP.NET) and asks for example code.

Is there any **standard/widely-acceptable** procedure for consuming JSON based web services from an ASP.NET application? I'm not familiar with the .NET framework, but can work my way through C#.

Any pointers are welcome.

Comment: Have been trying to solve that for quite a long time. Serializing as for itself isn't a big issue, I think the main issue is writing the POST request correctly. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864052/web-service-refuses-to-receive-parameters-and-reply-in-json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's quite a few JSON libraries available for .NET that will convert JSON to POCO objects:

> [Json.NET by Jason King](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx)
>   [JsonFx.NET](http://jsonfx.net/download/)

The [json.org website](http://www.json.org/) has references to these libraries and more.

There's even support for Classic ASP (which is not the same as ASP.NET):

> [JSON2.ASP](http://tforster.wik.is/ASP_Classic_Practices_For_The_21st_Century/JSON4ASP)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a library that already exists:

http://www.nateirwin.net/2008/11/20/json-array-to-c-using-jsonnet/

or you can build your own, something like this:

http://geekswithblogs.net/Mochalogic/articles/103330.aspx

JSON is fairly easy to work with though, so you should not have any issues.