# Sencha touch 2 failed to load bootstrap.json

Tags: iis, sencha-touch-2, cross-platform, windows-server-2008

My app and all the Sencha touch 2 example apps work perfectly (opening via desktop browser) when I host them on local IIS server, but when I copy the same code to an IIS instance running on Windows Server machine, I get this error on opening both touch examples as well as my app:-

```
GET http://servername/touch-2.3.1/examples/map/bootstrap.json 404 (Not Found)
```

This happens with all apps and the same code is running without errors on my local machine. Am I missing any configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! I had not added json MIME type to the IIS server (as was specified in the tutorial). Still keeping the question if someone else makes the same mistake. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332988/get-iis6-to-serve-json-files-inc-post-get/1121114#1121114) is the stackoverflow answer to enable json mime type in IIS.