# How to load json data with `localhost` using jquery getJson function?

Tags: jquery, json

I have a json file with my folder. as a sample it is like this:

json file :

```
{
  "name" : "testing"
}
```

in my view file i am trying like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var model = Backbone.Model.extend({});

    var view = Backbone.View.extend({
        model : model,
        initialize : function () {
            this.data = $.getJSON("OriginatingBanks.json", 
                function(data) {
                console.log(data); //data not at all loading.
            }).error(function(jqXhr, textStatus, error) {
                console.log("ERROR: " + textStatus + ", " + error);
            });
        }
    });

    var originatingBank = new view;

});
```

the json file sitting with html file as a sibling. what wrong goes here? any one help me?

**update**

While i try to open using the localhost, I am getting this error from local server:

[image: Here is the screen shot]

Comment: JavaScript in the browser can't access the system the browser is running on.

Comment: Look at the browser console and check the request being made.  Check the address and ensure that it's correct.

Comment: @Tichodroma as of HTML5 this is now not true. Plus I the OP says _the json file sitting with html file as a sibling_ which implies the JSON is next the the HTML on the _server_.

Comment: make sure you have correctly spelled the file name and there is not small/capital case problem

Comment: @BoristheSpider So the question title talking about "local file" is contradicting the question body (as you interpret it). Close vote for unclear question cast.

Comment: @Tichodroma agreed, question is unclear. I would guess that the OP wants to open a _local_ html file with the browser (using the `file://` URI) and then access a `.json` file that lives in the adjacent folder. But that is just a guess and needs clarification.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. You say "local file" in the title, and yet you say "json file sitting with html file as a sibling". And what do you mean by "view file"? Where are the files? In a server or your local machine? And how are you running it? Via browser, or Node.js, etc...?

Comment: I am working with `localhost`, I am trying to load the json file to my `Backbone` view function. the json file here with local folder. let me change the title then.

Comment: Do you get anything in the console? I think you have to remove `this.data = `. Now you are only saving the function in a variable. not running it. (Also i can't any Backbone so i'm not sure!)

Comment: can you see my update..

Comment: Thanks to all... I go the Answer from this Question:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332988/get-iis6-to-serve-json-files-inc-post-get][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332988/get-iis6-to-serve-json-files-inc-post-get